# Como trabalhar com arrays no Angular 5

Tags: angular

Estou pegando a lista assim:

```
listarTodosEstados() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.estadosUrl}`);
  }
```

Esse é meu component:

```
pesquisarEstados() {
    this.cidadesService.listarTodosEstados()
      .subscribe(dados => {
        console.log(this.estados = dados);
      });
  }
```

Esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor, gostaria de saber como faço para somente imprimir no console.log somente o atributo **codigo**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a função [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
pesquisarEstados() {
    this.cidadesService.listarTodosEstados().subscribe(dados => {
        this.estados = dados;
        console.log(this.estados.map(() => <any>e.codigo));
    });
}
```

Veja um exempo

```js
const estados = [{codigo: 1, nome:'Rio Grande do Sul'}, 
                 {codigo: 2, nome:'São Paulo'}, 
                 {codigo: 3, nome:'Minas Gerais'}];

console.log(estados.map((e) => e.codigo));
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela sugestão  :)

Comment: só tem um detalhe, ele não reconheceu o e.codigo por conta disso não chegou nem compilar.

Comment: @wladyband É porque você tipou a lista como `any`, né. Só colocar `any` antes.

Comment: desculpe minha falta de entendimento, eu copiei e colei do jeito como está  a sua sugestão, onde colocarei o any?

Comment: @wladyband tá ali no início da resposta, jovem

Comment: encontrei, valeu hahaha